# Using leaflet drawing tools with custom toolbar

Tags: angular, leaflet, drawing

I created a container from scratch as a toolbar with custom buttons and I want to use the leaflet drawing tools in my map with avoiding the toolbar given by leaflet.

In other words, I am looking for a way to get the drawing controls of leaflet and "put" them into my custom buttons. Is there a way to do it ?

PS: I already have the drawing tools in my map, I just want to move them into my new custom toolbar.

Toolbar with buttons to be used :

```
<div id="selection-tools-box">
 <div>
  <input id="radio-1" class="radio-custom" type="radio" checked (click)="cursorClick()">
  <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label"></label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input id="radio-2" class="radio-custom" type="radio" (click)="squareClick()">
  <label for="radio-2" class="radio-custom-label"></label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input id="radio-3" class="radio-custom" type="radio" (click)="circleClick()">
  <label for="radio-3" class="radio-custom-label"></label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input id="radio-4" class="radio-custom" type="radio" (click)="polygonClick()">
  <label for="radio-4" class="radio-custom-label"></label>
 </div>
```